# Ruby on Rails (Redmine) add route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

Please help me add the custom route in format:

```
/projects/any-project-name/estimated_time/report
```

controller: estimatedtime

method: report

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'welcome#index', :as => 'home'
.....
  get '/projects/:project_id/issues/gantt', :to => 'gantts#show', :as => 'project_gantt'
  get '/issues/gantt', :to => 'gantts#show'

.....
resources :time_entries, :controller => 'timelog', :except => [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy] do
      get 'report', :on => :collection
    end
.....
 resources :time_entries, :controller => 'timelog', :only => [:new, :create]
.....
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out: `get 'projects/:project_name_attribute/estimated_time/report' => 'estimatedtimes#report'`

Comment: forgot the `to:` parameter name in your solution.

Comment: This syntax doesn't need `to:` and it is supported in rails 6

Comment: correct. didn't know of it.